# Rotate file according to size

Tags: linux, centos, logrotate

I have the following setup: removed the line contaning `/var/log/maillog` from `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog` file, and added the following in `/etc/logrotate.conf` file:

```
...

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.

/var/log/maillog
{
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    size=50k
    postrotate
        touch /var/log/maillog
    endscript
}
```

Why does the `touch /var/log/maillog` line never get executed when the file size reaches 50k?

Comment: What do you see for that file if you run `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf`?

Comment: ...
`reading config info for /var/log/maillog`
...
`rotating pattern: /var/log/maillog
 51200 bytes (10 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/maillog
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/maillog, log->rotateCount is 10
dateext suffix '-20141210'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
destination /var/log/maillog-20141210 already exists, skipping rotation`

Comment: That last line seems like the key here I would think. `destination /var/log/maillog-20141210 already exists, skipping rotation` I'm not sure how that's supposed to work with date extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Because it is possible to get multiple rotations within the day when using size bound rotation it's not logical to use `dateext` option. From your comment showing the result of `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf`, it looks like it is enabled.

You can disable `dateext` in the block by adding `nodateext` option. Now the config will be:

```
...

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.

/var/log/maillog
{
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    size=50k
    nodateext ## ADD THIS LINE ##
    postrotate
        touch /var/log/maillog
    endscript
}
```